# Is there a continuous duty electric valve available?

Tags: solenoid-valve

I was searching and surprisingly unable to find a simple continuous duty electric water valve? Below is my requirement.

We get water from government. They release water only every 6th day., for few hours.  So most of the time our manual water valve is closed. Every 6th day, we manually open and  keep the water valve opened for few hours (typically 6 to 8 hours), because the timing is not consistent.

I want this process to be automated. If I have electric valve, I could simply connect to internet and schedule this. Only problem is, I see that solenoid valves cannot be activated for hours together. So I need a one (I don't care if its solenoid or anything, just something I could activate electrically), which I can activate and open electrically for few hours when needed.

Most of the aliexpress like platforms have valves, but not clear how long they can be operated. And numerous reviews suggest, even an hour of operation makes the coil/valve over heated, and even damaging the valve thereafter.

So can some one kindly suggest which device I should go after in the market? Do they have a different name than "continuous duty"? Kindly advice.

**Update:**
Kindly suggest something affordable (within $20 or so) if suggesting buying links. Kindly note, I am looking for ready made solution, not as a project. Something like plug and play. I intend to connect it to IOT, but that is separate(we have plug and play switches) so kindly focus only on suitable low cost continuous duty valves. Motorized valves are good fit as one of answers suggested,and am already searching for low cost ones but in vain so far.

Comment: Maybe "potable water solenoid valve?" https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Overview/Catalog/Water_(Potable)_Components/Potable_Water_Solenoid_Valves

Comment: They again fall under same solenoid valve categories Piloted Diaphragm , Zero Differential, Direct Acting - not sure which is fit for long run

Comment: I doubt that even plumbers buy from aliexpress. Speak with a plumber.

Comment: They appear to be quality items. Max temp is 52C and max fluid temp is 146C. The solenoid may get hot, but no failure should occur, given the high temperature rating. Maybe you can find a ball valve or gate valve actuated by a servo.

Comment: servo r ok for continuous operation? like hours?

Comment: What I am envisioning is a normal valve that you turn with your hand. But with a servomotor that turns the handle instead of your hand. Motor will only operate when changing state of valve. I don't know if such a thing exists, but it probably does.

Comment: oh I get it, servo can just open manually the valve like us by turning the valve handle, and then go back to its position (but then, should grab the handle and pull back while closing). seems complicated if there is a continuous duty valves available?  I am sure there should be applications which need valve to be opened or closed and remain that way for hours?

Comment: Self-contained battery powered irrigation timers operate for a few years on a single battery. Maybe that would work for you. I believe they use latching solenoids. Maybe search for "DC latching solenoid."

Comment: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Orbit-LCD-Single-Port-Hose-Faucet-Timer/16332345

Comment: no faucet timers hav duration in minutes, I need in hours (6 to 8 hours)

Comment: Why are you opening and closing this valve in the first place? Perhaps all you need is a simple passive check valve that only passes water in one direction. I assume you're just trying to prevent back-flow.

Comment: You want a valve that can be programmed via the internet to turn on for intervals of up to 8 hours, and you consider $135 to be prohibitively costly. To me, I feel that your expectations are not realistic. Also, I am pretty sure a solenoid valve will work fine if you buy one made from quality materials.

Comment: IOT part is easy. There are $5 switches available you can turn on via internet, schedule etc, like [this](https://bit.ly/2OCeipf). I am already checking in parallel with solenoid valve suppliers also, and so far not satisfactory answer from them. I really think motorized is a good option (or any that need not have continuous activation, instead one time turn knob on or off). So I am sure its realistic, only thing is due to lack of domain knowledge, I find difficulty getting to right device. I am hopeful.

Comment: This is clearly a shopping question, and therefore off-topic by longstanding tradition.

Comment: If I ask here, which T-shirt should I buy, its off-topic and a shopping question. If I ask which electric valve should I use for my project, with a technical requirement, I do not think it is. If so, then every question involving which resistor or any electronic device I should use for whatever purpose, all those would be shopping questions. Obviously one cannot do project without procuring parts, and there is nothing wrong asking which parts are right fit and how IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, @Paan. The site rules are quite specific about this. See [On-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question requires one more vote to be closed. You can edit to remove your shopping question. It's your choice. Regarding your choice of supplier, our general advice is, "No datasheet? No sale."

Comment: Searching for cheaper ones does not automatically make it shopping question. Its also highly subjective giving room for debate, so I do not want to waste my time arguing it further. I already got good valuable feedback from others and I am very thankful to them. That's it. Please do not send loose words like I am wasting others time. It hurts deeply as I highly respect whoever takes time to answer me. Please mind the words.

Comment: @Transistor thank you transistor, I checked it and I don't quite agree mine is shopping. I have my points on why so but do not want to argue much. The rules themselves say, its subjective, so its debatable. I did not ask which music player should I buy or what is best deal on price clearly. I wanted a valve with a specific technical requirement. Also cheaper one, as cost is also important. I dont think that automatically makes it "shopping". Anyway thank you for taking time to share.

Answer (score 1):

Search Web for "motorized water valve".  Unlike solenoid drives, motors need be energized only long enough to reach the desired open or closed state.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6n5TsR38GQ). It is great, but prohibitively costly ($135)

Comment: There are many different styles available, many at lower prices.  As an alternative solution: Use a solenoid valve with 2-level drive.  That is, drive solenoid initially with full rated voltage.  After a short time (ms to sec depending on valve) reduce the drive.  You may have to experiment with how much you can reduce the drive while still keeping the valve in the state (open/closed) that you wish.  Of course you must know enough electronics to build the 2-level drive (or find a published circuit) appropriate for whatever drive voltage you must use.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is not a project I have time for, but an annoyance I am trying to avoid, so preferring a ready made solution ;)

Comment: @mkeith Why do you discourage? Is it wrong to ask for help for readily available solution?

Comment: First of all, you did not specify everything up-front. So people suggested things, and you rejected them by introducing new information. Every suggestion, there was some new requirement disclosed by you that made it not suitable. Then you say "this is not a project I have time for..." Well, maybe we don't have time for it either. Maybe our time is just as valuable as your time.

Comment: I clearly explained my problem (including general overview, that is the bigger problem for which I am asking valve for) and what I am expecting for. Only thing I did not specifically say is I do not want to do it as a project, so when some one was kind enough to provide a project overview, I clarified that. Do you think all questions would be immediately answered by single answer,and one should take it w/o questioning? What is wrong in engaging with discussion when suggestions did not include some points?

Comment: I never specified I want as a project, and I never intended to disrespect any one any way. Not all are perfect. If I am so, I would have already known answer or would have gotten online. I wanted expert's POV on this subject, as may be I am searching in wrong directions. I do not know how this would be wasting any one's time. If I had not searched online and came here, still people would say, these questions could be answered online. So I had to specifically explain why online platforms could not help. Probably because I am searching in wrong direction.

Comment: Please try to keep an open mind, and if unable to answer please restrain. No need to bully some one because they did not ask "right" questions or in "right" way. I do not know why or how my question violates any rule here. I have explained problem in bigger perspective as much as possible.  I cannot anticipate every direction answers could go, and add them in question but did whenever possible. For eg, I added affordable price in question after people started suggestion $100 valves.  I am very thankful to all those who are answering here, and motorized valve was most useful answer so far.

Comment: OK. I will delete my comment. I was not trying to discourage you. I was just expressing my frustration at what appears to be a "moving target" question.

Answer (score 0):

Aliexpress has [motorised ball valves](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=&SearchText=motorised%20ball%20valve). They only use power while moving from one state to the other state.

I got a 3 way 1/2" one to switch the solar hot water down my chimney.

Most of them have no visible indication of which state they are in. (annoying) 
A few have a visible indicator, and even fewer have a manual knob as well.

Comment: yeah, something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6n5TsR38GQ) would be great or at least LED indicators. Also option to operate manually in case of power failure.  I am already in touch with these suppliers as well, with no results yet.